# How to check if file has been sent over Bluetooth successfully?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want to delete the file(.txt or .js) once the transfer has been complete.
Bluetooth gives a Toast once the file has been transferred(or not)

Is there any way to catch that Toast or to know when file transfer is 
complete? Does Bluetooth fire an event or set a Flag? Please help, stuck for 3 days now.

Comment: Add more information:
You are using an external library to bluetooth communication, or you've programmed yourself?
For the communication system is used packets or just pour data?
What do you mean : Bluetooth gives a Toast

Comment: @Majkl No I am not using an external library. The question is : After bluetooth transfer is complete[in Android] we see a toast "file sent", How do I catch this toast? How does bluetooth/Android understand the file has been sent?